# R - unable to load shared object digest.dll in digest package

Tags: r, digest, shared-objects

I was working on a Shiny App until I got this message:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : unable to load shared object 'E:/Users/B145441/Desktop/library/digest/libs/x64/digest.dll':
LoadLibrary failure: Can not find the specified module.
```

when I tried to load shiny package. It's seems to be an issue when R tries to load digest packge... Then I try with:

```
dyn.load("E:/Users/B145441/Desktop/library/digest/libs/x64/digest.dll")
```

And I got the same message.

I deleted all my .RData and .Rhistory files and reinstall R. Didn't work.

I read maybe the problem has to do with the permissions because I'm connected to a network where the libraries are saved on a shared space, so I change the library directory to a local path ("E:/Users/B145441/Desktop/library/...") editing my Rprofile file but I'm getting the same error.

Here you have some info about my R software...

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Mexico.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Mexico.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Mexico.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Mexico.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.1.1    tools_3.2.2
```

And my workstation...

```
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Compilation 7601
System Type x64
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU
Windows directory C:\windows
System directory C:\windows\system32
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any statement that you actually installed the 'digest'-package.

Comment: The package was installed correctly from the CRAN, but I if download the .tar, and installed with ```install.packages("E:/Users/B145441/Downloads/digest_0.6.8.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")```

 I recive the next message:
`Installing package into "E:/Users/B145441/Desktop/library"`
then...
```Warning: command executed 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="digest.dll" OBJECTS="aes.o crc32.o digest.o init.o md5.o pmurhash.o raes.o sha1.o sha2.o sha256.o xxhash.o"' has status 127```

Comment: If you are going to install from source you need to have the proper RTools package. Were you able lo load the digest package after installing it as a binary package?

Comment: You were right, the package is now istalled with no error message, source type or CRAN works fine, but the error remains.